# Chromecast icon not shown with local ip

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm createing a chromecast app for android. I registered my application on Google Cast SDK Developer Console and used the id from there.

As a test I first entered https://google.com as url for my application. that worked perfectly fine. i then changed this url to a local one http://192.168.0.18:8100. Problem is, it allways opens google on chromecast. so i created a new application, but since i did that, the cast button is not shown anymore.

Is my local url valid for chromecast and maybe does it take some time to accept my changed in cast sdk console?
thanks

Comment: Make sure you reboot your chromecast and enter correct serial number. Since this is not a coding issue, please contact https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1 to get help.

Comment: Have you tried registering a local 192.168.*.* URL with a default port? I'm not sure if non-default ports work.